# Allow User to Change Font and Boldness in Description

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have been searching and have yet to find any rails gems related to allowing a User to change the font or bold certain words when submitting their own content in a comment or in my case for a Description. I want the User to Be able to bold or emphasize words **Similar to this site's Question box** I can *initialize and* **bold words** at my disposal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tinymce` gem is perfect for this.

It allows for perfect text editing. With it's user interface, you can do stuff like add links and images too.

To get started, add this to your gemfile

```
gem 'tinymce-rails'
```

then run `bundle`

You also need to include this library in your `application.js` file

```
//= require tinymce
```

Then in a `text-area` tag, add this

```
<%= text_area_tag :content, "", :class => "tinymce", :rows => 40, :cols => 120 %>
```

That's it. I've used this gem when creating a blogging application, and I was able to create a text box similar to StackOverflow.

All this information is also available at

https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails